# Getting the NServiceBus Distributor Sample To Work

Tags: msmq, nservicebus

I'm trying to use the Distributor in the NServiceBus FullDuplex sample but I can't get it working. I've been following the this guide [Getting the NServiceBus Distributor Working](http://www.colourcoding.net/Blog/archive/2009/04/22/getting-the-nservicebus-distributor-working.aspx), but it doesn't work.

There are two problems, one the distributordatabus isn't being created I think the Distributor should create this one. This is the error I get when starting the Distributor, I think it has something to do would it.

```
2009-11-13 11:27:15,811 [7] ERROR NServiceBus.Distributor.EndpointRunner [(null)
] <(null)> - Problem occurred when starting the endpoint.
System.InvalidOperationException: No message serializer has been configured.
   bij NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Msmq.MsmqTransport.CheckConfiguration() in
d:\Code\Other\NServiceBus\trunk\src\impl\unicast\NServiceBus.Unicast.Msmq\MsmqTr
ansport.cs:regel 229
```

The second problem is when I start the client, I doesn't start because it can't find the distributordatabus. This is the exception.

> Exception when starting endpoint,
>   error has been logged. Reason: The
>   destination queue 'distributordatabus'
>   could not be found. You may have
>   misconfigured the destination for this
>   kind of message
>   (NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.CompletionMessage)
>   in the MessageEndpointMappings of the
>   UnicastBusConfig section in your
>   configuration file.It may also be the
>   case that the given queue just hasn't
>   been created yet, or has been deleted.

This is something I don't understand. Why does the client need the remote queue to exist?

One more thing, I'm using the trunk version.

Regards,

Jochen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed for version 2.0 and available here:

http://teamcity.codebetter.com/repository/download/bt96/7268:id/NServiceBus.2.0.0.948.zip

Comment: Started up the distributor from this release and it worked. Thanks.